# Xcode 5 document template Apps OS X: Where to do the Apps lifecycle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, automatic-ref-counting, application-lifecycle

I am new to programming for Mac (not iOS but OS X) and so have run into a problem. The template providing a document based application doesn't come with an appDelegate class. Only class provided and used is the NSDocument subclass.

My Problem: Where do I put the `- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender` (or equivalent) method I need in order to call a NSAlert? If I place it into my NSDocument subclass, it never gets called.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Just had to implement my own AppDelegate class (however I didn't know how to do this. I just looked in a test app (non document base) how it goes).

Also, I looked here: [X-Code Interface Builder Not showing App Delegate Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796977/x-code-interface-builder-not-showing-app-delegate-object)